# How to specify POST method instead of GET using the Google translate API v2 library

Tags: c#, .net, google-translate

I need to be able to specify POST method instead of GET using the Google translate API v2 library.
Here is my code:

```
Google.Apis.Translate.v2.TranslationsResource.ListRequest request =  this.client.Translations.List( cadena, idiomaDestino );
request.Source = idiomaOriginal;
request.Format = Google.Apis.Translate.v2.TranslationsResource.Format.Html;
TranslationsListResponse response = request.Fetch();
if ( response.Translations.Count > 0 )
{
    //Do something with the translations
}
```

Comment: I need help with this as well.

Comment: If you're using a Google API, why not just use the method that does what you need?  If you want to  do something specific, why not use WebClient or HttpClient?